# Striped background colour on every other x block in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was referring to [How can I use different background color each x value in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260148/how-can-i-use-different-background-color-each-x-value-in-ggplot), but applying in my plot failed. I need to get everyother x block in light blue (with alpha = 0.5) and white in my plot.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(grid)
library(magrittr)

min = 0
max = 1.05
dput(dat)
structure(list(Model = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3), `Mean of Estimated effect` = c(8.42134082e-05, 0.000107182331002, 
0.06469990623, -0.00029947095693, -0.00034541286898, 0.0670277761, 
0.0002547219173, 4.36015852e-05, 0.071130021, 0.000517331991647, 
0.000494989755938, 0.0648010748, 9.76527798300001e-06, 3.757211326e-05, 
0.06672561808, -0.000609598746152, -0.00055061312495, 0.07007563221, 
-0.00013330768348, -0.000109716312365, 0.06642985636, 7.528789179e-05, 
0.000153617275595, 0.0690836734, -0.00020439346245, -0.000306403576952, 
0.07436113997, 0.000269610057977, 9.354964844e-05, 0.07184994794, 
-7.467951115e-05, 0.00029718963203, 0.08102026515, 0.000240501348501, 
0.000140737935046, 0.10060236794), `SE of Estimated effect` = c(0.00041587572792327, 
0.000414449729670283, 0.000616135730833483, 0.000412531512828632, 
0.000422939387882767, 0.000646629322460781, 0.000390838561947719, 
0.000391190366461578, 0.000701139256016304, 0.000419328960414079, 
0.000420342096506397, 0.000635138379236672, 0.000399126779797598, 
0.000397962271538008, 0.000632132868979739, 0.000370129054192697, 
0.000380284824509253, 0.000618405324619559, 0.000398097560988969, 
0.000395734838536576, 0.000627329259114512, 0.000399490465252409, 
0.00040574867474133, 0.000690453674466185, 0.000378636959338486, 
0.000377335931719156, 0.000682175767005444, 0.000385560736191996, 
0.000365144491024794, 0.000655690612854308, 0.000349146936726498, 
0.000338834174317276, 0.000726274457241534, 0.000286619966081066, 
0.000283112736458343, 0.000808302610105675), `Mean(-log(p-value))` = c(0.488220857481045, 
0.48576208789347, 7.96490102269108, 0.515345198260521, 0.519739431307012, 
8.47168151648598, 0.515371587318554, 0.494282924519454, 9.95156713506716, 
0.481639635231681, 0.482255050525165, 7.9811536466609, 0.507117594502525, 
0.499443060803304, 8.55823656235146, 0.492394507424854, 0.483356446112112, 
10.2115381709774, 0.470531924845609, 0.463860223536673, 8.21804442366304, 
0.502753724531074, 0.509944047028126, 9.27620729911404, 0.514659567488252, 
0.486727551537996, 11.9973898493522, 0.499655548016483, 0.513929160490333, 
12.3292114042, 0.533479551273273, 0.549288142818748, 19.5628325439984, 
0.624502585449497, 0.613653139717795, 47.2421595108874), `SE(-log(p-value))` = c(0.0162490340208818, 
0.0161242016927077, 0.0887707677808478, 0.0157626750337117, 0.0160533479564987, 
0.0924712565386313, 0.016927101771745, 0.0159422669604518, 0.0986313502861951, 
0.0161903055182046, 0.0163260099226977, 0.0866878533924906, 0.0151905022109008, 
0.0150938754282607, 0.0922934049006777, 0.0156986222898782, 0.0155331696234266, 
0.0973805332524809, 0.0153925013149776, 0.0152696442511198, 0.0867476750073371, 
0.0168097673806445, 0.0168973377719266, 0.0924433911636156, 0.016285105072155, 
0.0155756498639701, 0.106040294517106, 0.015964949251676, 0.0163830816011049, 
0.108274049530958, 0.0186753410895363, 0.018128341416302, 0.144781286646691, 
0.0214588027247813, 0.0206202856108384, 0.23764129682392), `Var G` = c(0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), `Var G_E` = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `Var GxE` = c(0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05), `Cov between G and G_E` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4), `Res Var of y` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5), `Res Var of E` = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5), `Cov Res of y and E` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), `Mean Type 1 Err` = c(0.068, 0.068, 0.998, 
0.067, 0.063, 1, 0.085, 0.076, 1, 0.078, 0.076, 1, 0.07, 0.079, 
1, 0.084, 0.075, 1, 0.062, 0.054, 1, 0.073, 0.086, 1, 0.096, 
0.072, 1, 0.073, 0.086, 1, 0.089, 0.095, 1, 0.121, 0.123, 1), 
    `95% CI` = c("(0.0542159512479098, 0.0817840487520902)", 
    "(0.0542159512479098, 0.0817840487520902)", "(0.98421595124791, 1.01178404875209)", 
    "(0.0532159512479098, 0.0807840487520902)", "(0.0492159512479098, 0.0767840487520902)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", "(0.0712159512479098, 0.0987840487520902)", 
    "(0.0622159512479098, 0.0897840487520902)", "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", 
    "(0.0642159512479098, 0.0917840487520902)", "(0.0622159512479098, 0.0897840487520902)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", "(0.0562159512479098, 0.0837840487520902)", 
    "(0.0652159512479098, 0.0927840487520902)", "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", 
    "(0.0702159512479098, 0.0977840487520902)", "(0.0612159512479098, 0.0887840487520902)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", "(0.0482159512479098, 0.0757840487520902)", 
    "(0.0402159512479098, 0.0677840487520902)", "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", 
    "(0.0592159512479098, 0.0867840487520902)", "(0.0722159512479098, 0.0997840487520902)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", "(0.0822159512479098, 0.10978404875209)", 
    "(0.0582159512479098, 0.0857840487520902)", "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", 
    "(0.0592159512479098, 0.0867840487520902)", "(0.0722159512479098, 0.0997840487520902)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", "(0.0752159512479098, 0.10278404875209)", 
    "(0.0812159512479098, 0.10878404875209)", "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)", 
    "(0.10721595124791, 0.13478404875209)", "(0.10921595124791, 0.13678404875209)", 
    "(0.98621595124791, 1.01378404875209)"), `Corr between G and G_E` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 
    0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 
    0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 
    0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 0.447213595499958, 
    0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916, 0.894427190999916), 
    `Corr Res of y and E` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06, 
    0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8), LL = c(0.0542159512479098, 0.0542159512479098, 
    0.98421595124791, 0.0532159512479098, 0.0492159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0712159512479098, 0.0622159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0642159512479098, 0.0622159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0562159512479098, 0.0652159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0702159512479098, 0.0612159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0482159512479098, 0.0402159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0592159512479098, 0.0722159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0822159512479098, 0.0582159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0592159512479098, 0.0722159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.0752159512479098, 0.0812159512479098, 
    0.98621595124791, 0.10721595124791, 0.10921595124791, 0.98621595124791
    ), UL = c(0.0817840487520902, 0.0817840487520902, 1.01178404875209, 
    0.0807840487520902, 0.0767840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0987840487520902, 0.0897840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0917840487520902, 0.0897840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0837840487520902, 0.0927840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0977840487520902, 0.0887840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0757840487520902, 0.0677840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.0867840487520902, 0.0997840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 
    0.10978404875209, 0.0857840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 0.0867840487520902, 
    0.0997840487520902, 1.01378404875209, 0.10278404875209, 0.10878404875209, 
    1.01378404875209, 0.13478404875209, 0.13678404875209, 1.01378404875209
    )), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

`Type 1 Error` <- dat$`Mean Type 1 Err`
subcategory <- as.factor(dat$`Corr Res of y and E`)
category <- as.factor(round(dat$`Corr between G and G_E`,3))
LL <- dat$LL
UL <- dat$UL
Model <- as.factor(dat$Model)

nFac <- 4; nDat <- 10
df <- data.frame(x = gl(nFac, nDat), 
                 y = runif(nFac * nDat))
rec <- data.frame(xmin = head(seq <- seq(0.5, nFac + .5, 1), -1), 
                  xmax = tail(seq, -1), 
                  alpha = c(.5, 0, .5, 0))

d <- data.frame(category, subcategory, `Type 1 Error`, LL, UL,Model)

ggplot(data = d,  aes(x = subcategory, y = `Type 1 Error`, color = Model)) +
  scale_x_discrete(seq_len(nFac)) +
  geom_rect(data = rec, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, 
                xmax = xmax, 
                alpha = alpha), 
            ymin = -Inf, 
            ymax = Inf, 
            fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_errorbar(data = d, aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), width = 0.5, position="dodge")+
  facet_wrap( ~ category,
              labeller = as_labeller(\(x) paste("Cor(G\u0079, G\u1D07) =", x)),
              strip.position = "top") +
  theme_classic2()+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    #aspect.ratio = 1,
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x =element_blank(),
    legend.position="none") +
  ggtitle("a. Var(GxE) = 0")+
  xlab("Cor(\u0190\u0079, \u0190\u1D07)")+
  geom_abline(aes(slope=0,intercept=0.05),linetype="dashed")+ ylim(min, max)
```

I'm not getting the plot I expect.

Without `geom_rect(...)` I'm getting the following plot:
[image]

Error code:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the global aesehtitics `x`, `y` and `color` are inherited by each `geom` layer. As a side effect this means that `ggplot2` requires the columns mapped on these aesthetics to be present in the data used for each layer, which is not the case for the `geom_rect`, i.e. your dataset `rec` has no columns `subcategory`, `Type 1 Error` or `Model`. To fix that add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_rect` to prevent the global aes to be inherited.

Note: I also removed the expansion of the x scale by adding `expand = c(0, 0)` to `scale_x_discrete`.

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = subcategory, y = `Type 1 Error`, color = Model)) +
  scale_x_discrete(seq_len(nFac), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = rec,
    aes(
      xmin = xmin,
      xmax = xmax,
      alpha = alpha
    ),
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = Inf,
    fill = "lightblue",
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = d, aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL),
    width = 0.5, position = "dodge"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~category,
    labeller = as_labeller(\(x) paste("Cor(G\u0079, G\u1D07) =", x)),
    strip.position = "top"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  ggtitle("a. Var(GxE) = 0") +
  xlab("Cor(\u0190\u0079, \u0190\u1D07)") +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0, intercept = 0.05), linetype = "dashed") +
  ylim(min, max)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I also needed to get rid of alpha legend, so for that I added the following line to your code and it worked!

` + guides(alpha="none")`